# Trying to rename a file in R, but "No such file or directory"

Tags: r, rename, working-directory

I've been trying to find the answer to this question online, but can't find any solutions.

I have set a wd, and when I enter getwd() and list.files() it all works.

However, when I try to rename my file from my wd, I get the error 'No such file or directory'.

Here is an example:

```
>file.rename('codebook', 'codebook2')
[1] FALSE
Warning message:
In file.rename('codebook', 'codebook2'):
cannot rename file 'codebook' to 'codebook2', reason 'No such file or directory'
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does `list.files()` show exactly? Does this file not have an extension of any sort? If it does have an extension, you'll need to include that in the name, ie "codebook.R" rather than just "codebook" if it's an R file. Or is `codebook` actually a directory/folder rather than a file?

Comment: list.files returns this: [1] "example.sav"         "codebook.csv" "example.sav"        
[4] "example.Rproj"        "example.R"

Comment: Then your command should look like `file.rename('codebook.csv', 'codebook2.csv')` The extension at the end is part of the file name; and file names must match exactly when renaming them.

Comment: I tried to rename using the file extension (codebook is a file), but it said object 'codebook2.csv' (new file name) not found

Comment: What exactly did you type? Did you have the new file name in quotes? Can you copy the error exactly?

Comment: Ah, I got it to work! thanks so much!